# ListPlot curves exceed PlotRange, thus overflowing the Frame

Tags: plotting, frame

[Update, 4/1/20:  This has been confirmed as a bug by Wolfram Technical Support.]

When I restrict the PlotRange in ListPlot and its variants (ListLogPlot, ListLogLinearPolt, and ListLogLogPlot), the curves are drawn well beyond the PlotRange, and thus well outside the Frame.

Is there an option or setting I can use to correct this?  I have a lot of plots, and they change often, so manually correcting each one with PlotRangePadding is not practical or desirable.  Please see the two toy examples below.

```
SKorea3={{5, 1.96147*10^-6}, {6, 1.96147*10^-6}, {7, 3.92294*10^-6}, {8, 
  3.92294*10^-6}, {9, 5.88441*10^-6}, {10, 7.84587*10^-6}, {11, 
  7.84587*10^-6}, {12, 7.84587*10^-6}, {13, 7.84587*10^-6}, {14, 
  0.0000215762}, {15, 0.0000235376}, {16, 0.000029422}, {17, 
  0.000029422}, {18, 0.0000313835}, {19, 0.0000372679}, {20, 
  0.0000451138}, {21, 0.0000470752}, {22, 0.0000470752}, {23, 
  0.0000490367}, {24, 0.0000529596}, {25, 0.0000549211}, {26, 
  0.0000549211}, {27, 0.0000549211}, {28, 0.0000549211}, {29, 
  0.0000549211}, {30, 0.0000568826}, {31, 0.0000588441}, {32, 
  0.0000608055}, {33, 0.0000608055}, {34, 0.000203993}, {35, 
  0.00040014}, {36, 0.000849316}, {37, 0.0011808}, {38, 
  0.0016339}, {39, 0.00191635}, {40, 0.00247341}, {41, 
  0.00346395}, {42, 0.00458395}, {43, 0.00617863}, {44, 
  0.00732805}, {45, 0.00850297}, {46, 0.0101722}, {47, 
  0.0110254}, {48, 0.0119414}, {49, 0.012932}, {50, 0.0138107}, {51, 
  0.0143462}, {52, 0.0146679}, {53, 0.0147365}, {54, 0.0152112}, {55, 
  0.0154348}, {56, 0.0156506}, {57, 0.0158604}, {58, 0.0160095}, {59, 
  0.0161547}, {60, 0.0163194}, {61, 0.0165018}, {62, 0.0168}, {63, 
  0.0169706}, {64, 0.017259}, {65, 0.0174512}, {66, 0.0175767}};
UK3={{-13, 0.}, {-12, 0.}, {-11, 0.}, {-10, 0.}, {-9, 0.}, {-8, 0.}, {-7, 
  0.}, {-6, 0.}, {-5, 0.}, {-4, 3.02199*10^-6}, {-3, 
  3.02199*10^-6}, {-2, 3.02199*10^-6}, {-1, 3.02199*10^-6}, {0, 
  3.02199*10^-6}, {1, 3.02199*10^-6}, {2, 3.02199*10^-6}, {3, 
  4.53298*10^-6}, {4, 4.53298*10^-6}, {5, 4.53298*10^-6}, {6, 
  0.000012088}, {7, 0.000012088}, {8, 0.0000135989}, {9, 
  0.0000135989}, {10, 0.0000135989}, {11, 0.0000135989}, {12, 
  0.0000135989}, {13, 0.0000135989}, {14, 0.0000135989}, {15, 
  0.0000135989}, {16, 0.0000135989}, {17, 0.0000135989}, {18, 
  0.0000135989}, {19, 0.0000135989}, {20, 0.0000196429}, {21, 
  0.0000196429}, {22, 0.0000196429}, {23, 0.0000226649}, {24, 
  0.0000302199}, {25, 0.0000347529}, {26, 0.0000543958}, {27, 
  0.0000604398}, {28, 0.0000770607}, {29, 0.000128435}, {30, 
  0.000173764}, {31, 0.000246292}, {32, 0.000311265}, {33, 
  0.000412501}, {34, 0.000485029}, {35, 0.0005772}, {36, 
  0.000689013}, {37, 0.000689013}, {38, 0.00120577}, {39, 
  0.00172253}, {40, 0.00172253}, {41, 0.00233146}, {42, 
  0.00294644}, {43, 0.00396787}, {44, 0.00406306}, {45, 
  0.00601829}, {46, 0.00758217}, {47, 0.00858698}, {48, 0.0100481}};
ListPlot[{SKorea3, UK3}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Days", "% of Population Confirmed Infected"},
 Joined -> True, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 PlotRange -> {{20, 40}, {0, .004}}, 
 PlotLabels -> {"S. Korea", "UK"}]
ListLogLogPlot[{SKorea3, UK3}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Days", "% of Population Confirmed Infected"},
 Joined -> True, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 PlotRange -> {{20, 40}, {0, .004}}, PlotLabels -> {"S. Korea", "UK"}]
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't look right to me - it seems to be a bug. Documentation for `PlotRangeClipping` says: The default setting for `PlotRangeClipping` is `False` for `Graphics` and `True` for functions such as `Plot.`

Comment: This occurrs due to the `PlotLabels`. Removing it, one can see that plot looks good. You can use `Callout` instead

Comment: Another option is to replace 'PlotLabels' with 'PlotLegends'.

Comment: @VictorK.  Good point, but the problem with PlotLegends is I've got 9 curves in my actual plots and, with that many, some of the auto-generated colors are hard to distinguish.  And, even if they weren't, it's easier on the reader with the pointers (which PlotLabels provides, but PlotLegends doesn't).

Comment: @Rom38  May I ask what syntax you used?  Following the Wolfram documentation, I tried the following, and got a result no different from that with PlotLabels (i.e, the same spillover of the Frame):   `ListLogLogPlot[{Callout[SKorea3, "SKorea"], Callout[UK3, "UK"]}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Days", "% of Population Confirmed Infected"}, 
 Joined -> True, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 PlotRange -> {{20, 40}, {0, .004}}]` `ListPlot`, with `Callout`, behaves the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitely looks like a bug to me. Seems like 'PlotLabels' messes up the plot range. I don't know of any great solution, but if you're setting the `PlotRange` of each graph, you could pass those same settings to `Select` and have it filter the data first. Not ideal, but it seems to work.

With the data as defined in your code:

```
ListPlot[
  Select[#, 20 <= #[[1]] <= 40 &] & /@ {SKorea3, UK3}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Days", "% of Population Confirmed Infected"}, 
  Joined -> True, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
  PlotRange -> {{20, 40}, {0, .004}}, 
  PlotLabels -> {"S. Korea", "UK"}
]

ListLogLogPlot[
  Select[#, 20 <= #[[1]] <= 40 &] & /@ {SKorea3, UK3}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Days", "% of Population Confirmed Infected"}, 
  Joined -> True, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
  PlotRange -> {{20, 40}, {0, .004}}, 
  PlotLabels -> {"S. Korea", "UK"}
]
```

[image: Corrected plots.]

If you want to get rid of the little gap at the end, just add `PlotRangePadding -> 0` to all of the graphs.

Comment: Very nice workaround, thanks! Upvoted your answer. Since you and others agree it appears to be a bug, I sent an email to Wolfram Tech Support to see if they have a fix.  I'm going to hold off a bit on accepting yours as the answer until I hear back from them.

Comment: Wolfram TS confirms it's a bug, and they don't currently have a fix.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like a bug with default placement of the callouts. Adding the positions manually solves problem.

```
 ListPlot[{Callout[SKorea3, "SK", {33, 0.0015}, CalloutStyle -> Blue], 
  Callout[UK3, "UK", {36, 0.003}, CalloutStyle -> Orange]}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Days", "% of Population Confirmed Infected"}, 
 Joined -> True, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 PlotRange -> {{20, 40}, {0, .004}}]
```

[image]

**UPD.:** Automatization of the Callout positions for batch processing.

I synthesized couple of the additional datasets from your's arrays:

```
data2 = {First@#, Last@#*1.22} & /@ UK3;
data3 = {First@#, 0.0001 + 1.05 Last@#} & /@ SKorea3;
```

Next, making the arrays of labels, positions, etc as well as final list of pre-formated Callouts:

```
xrange = {20, 40}; (*The x-range of Plot*)
yrange = {0, 0.004}; (*The y-range of Plot *)

num = 4; (*number of the curves for labelling*)

xpos = Table[
   xrange[[1]] + 0.9 (xrange[[2]] - xrange[[1]])*i/num, {i, 1, num}];
ypos = Table[
   yrange[[1]] + 0.8 (yrange[[2]] - yrange[[1]])*i/num, {i, 1, num}];

d = {SKorea3, UK3, data2, data3}; (*list of datasets*)
l = {"SK", "UK", "D2", "D3"}; (*list of labels*)

res = Table[Callout[d[[i]], l[[i]], {xpos[[i]], ypos[[i]]}, CalloutStyle -> ColorData[97][i]], {i, 1, num}]; (*array of callouts*)
```

Finally, let's draw it:

```
ListPlot[res, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Days", "% of Population Confirmed Infected"}, 
 Joined -> True, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 PlotRange -> {xrange, yrange}]
```

[image]

Playing with definitions of `xpos` and `ypos` one can shift a bit labels for the best view of namelly your curves. Such a way allows easy re-calculations after the update of the datasets.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely not an option for me for my current use case. I've got several plots, with nine different curves each, that need to be replotted regularly (with new ranges) as new data is added. Thus, as I indicated in my OP, I need something that works automatically, as opposed to something that requires manual adjustment for each individual curve in each individual plot.   Useful to know about for producing something for final publication, though.

Comment: @theorist, it can work automatically. You just need pre-defining the label positions. It can be done easy as a list of typical coordinates for labels if you know the axis ranges.

Comment: I'd be *very* interested in that, but I'm not sure if we mean the same thing by "automatic".   [I contacted Wolfram Tech Support to explain what I wanted, and they said it can only be done manually.]  But maybe you've thought of something they haven't.  I'll post a separate question on this when I have a chance, and let you know when it's posted.

Comment: @theorist, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for doing that, but what I meant in this case by automatic (that's why I wanted to explain it first before you did all this work!) was getting the pointers to automatically touch the lines, rather than be offset from them, without my having to manually specify the endpoints of the pointers.  When I get a chance I'll post a question with a detailed data set, to which you can respond..

Comment: @theorist, touching of the lines is realized automatically anyway. The positions here provide just the COARSE alighnment of the labels.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't seem to solve my issue -- I don't see the automatic touching to which you refer.  Take a look, for instance, at D2 in your lower plot.  Because it's not actually touching the line for D2 (which is green), it looks like it's pointing at the line for D3 (which is orange).  This issue can also be seen in your upper plot.   I'd asked Wolfram TS if there was a way the label pointers could be made to automatically touch the curves to which they corresponded (so the pointers woudn't need to be manually readjusted each time the plots changed shape), and they didn't know of one.